# Like button of facebook not showing comment box

Tags: asp.net, facebook-like

The problem is when you click the button, the comment box is not displayed, but the LIKE works normal, appear on my profile. It works fine sometimes but most of the times the comment box is not displayed.
Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong

This is the script which I have written on my master page below body tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {.
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];.
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;.
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;.
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=292455817458061";.
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);.
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

.

and this is the code which I have written in my aspx page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/IT.FinishingSchool" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You get nothing because the http://www.facebook.com/IT.FinishingSchool is not public. So there's nothing according to facebook that's really sharable.  So all you will get is the like.

Comment: Nope... Its not the case.. it is working sometimes and shows up the comment box and allows me to share and sometimes it doesnt shows up the comment box to share a comment. I dont know whats the problem is...When i click on like, it postbacks but sometimes doesnt show the comment box. I think probably the problem is with javascript... please let me know if i am doing anything wrong...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the HTML or JS you posted in your question.  Everything looks as normal as normal can be.  I believe you get it sometimes probably because that user already has rights to see the http://www.facebook.com/IT.FinishingSchool, and when you don't see it, that particular user cannot see it.  Another reason why the popup wont show would be due the last FAQ item on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I am not able to understand the problem... It works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt work... I tried the solution of FAQ but was of no use...Please help me out...

Comment: It works when the page is loaded the second time.. I am not able to understand the problem... I have written the script in master page and the code for button in my page..I have tried writing the script in the same page where my button is present..but was of no use..I dont know how its working the page is loaded the second time around.. Please help me out...

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/#!/IT.FinishingSchool
I have not changed it.. the same thing works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt work. I think its the problem with HTML edge or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For those having the same problem when using iframe option:

try using `XFBML` version instead, that worked for me!

You can get the `XFBML` code from [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)